# Many to many relationships in EER diagrams, N:M vs N:M

Tags: relationship, data-modeling, entity-relationship

In the course book I am using, many-to-many relationships are denoted with N:M, but elsewhere I see references to N:N. Is there a difference and, if not, why use N:M at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both refer to the same type of relationships: many to many. I find using different letter better to interpret (`N:M`) because the amount of possible relationships between the entities might not always be the same in each direction.

Using `N:N` *might* indicate that the amount of links between each entity is the same the other way around, and this has nothing to do with how to model the relationship, just an additional tip about the business. However, it's often not used to depict this kind of cardinality, they just mean `N:M`.

Answer (score 0):

N:M makes it explicit that the number of related items need not be same on both sides. For example, if each student has 12 teachers, and each teacher 30 students, one might think that N:N is wrong, because 12 is not 30. But when people say N:N, they just have "N" represent any arbitrary number that is not "1" (i.e. terminology-wise, "1" reads as "one", and "N" reads as "many"). They both mean the same thing.